# React: is useEffect always the correct way to go?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-context, react-state, react-usememo

I am currently asking myself, if useEffect is always the right way to go.
I am thinking about that, because of my current project.

Imagine you have to following:

- a state `query` which is just a query for backend. A query also knows a `sorting`. This will be filled by a `loadQuery` method, which gets a configured `query` from backend. But the initial state is a empty `query` and NOT undefined.
- a method `loadData` which loads data from backend of type `Entity[]`. This method consumes the state `query`. This can directly be triggered, because of the empty `query` which is a valid query.
- a method `loadView` which loads views from backend of type `View`. A `view` is just a JSON, which describes the cells of a table and has a `sorting` property.
- a useEffect, which calls `loadData` and `loadView`. As dependency, we have the `query`.
- a useEffect function which listen on the loaded `view`. If the loaded view has a `sorting` property, then it will manipulate the `query` state. This will lead to trigger the useEffect again from one point above.

This is the current scenario (shortened of course).
We also have

- `view` switch button, which changes to `query` again. This will lead that the useEffect for loading data will be triggered.
- a infinity loading in the table (which will also call `loadData` with an offset),
- The `query` can change, if the user changes the query in a `FilterDialog`

Sometimes the useEffect for loading data, will be triggered 3 times in a row.

Sure, a solution will be to remember a boolean if some data got already loaded or not... But since we have more then one useEffect, it is hard to do this. It is also hard to remember a boolean for this, because if a `componentDidUpdate` cycle occurr, then you have to reset these booleans, because everything should be executed as before. But this can lead to problems, because everything is async.

Maybe some one else had the same problem, to have too much useEffects and this leads to unnecessary things and can share his experience with me :)

Comment: Have you tried memoizing the `view` object and recreating it only when `sorting` changes?

Useeffect may be clunky sometimes but I usually don't face issues with nesting useEffects unless it starts involving some async waterfalls which need to be interrupted

Comment: @dkusnietsov But the `query` itself (not the `sorting`) can also change. The user can click on a button to change the `query` in a dialog.:/